# Set Tablet Network for a specific SSID permanently

Tags: samsung, mac-address

Hallo Stack Exchange Community,

I have android 10 and 11 Samsung Tablets and I want to set the tablet (device) MAC on a specific SSID.

I dont need to know how to set it via Wifi Settings, because it changes after a restart.
Source: https://www.easytechguides.com/disable-device-security-on-a-samsung-galaxy/

Is there any way to set it permanently? If not a simple no will do, but I still kinda hope that I did not find the right way to do it.

Other Sources:
https://wifi-helpcenter.nokia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056890733-Issues-with-random-MAC-addresses-Android-10-iOS-14- https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization

Comment: Similar to your last question on SO you still don't tell us if you want to use the non-randomized real device MAC or set an arbitrary MAC (forged MAC). To use the device real MAC you should be able to do so in the Wifi settings of the connected Wifi network as described in your second link.

Comment: Like I already posted I need the device MAC permanently not only till the next restart, so the second link is no help, because the describtion is like the first link. If there is no setting that can help me just tell me instead of telling me to use the second link eventhough I wrote that it is not the solution I am searching for. Apperently device MAC is not the right term in your eyes so I will use yours I need the non-randomized real device MAC.

Comment: If you specify for one Wifi to use the device MAC address instead of the generated privacy MAC this setting is saved to the Wifi entry like the PSK and applied every time, even after a device restart. Everything else would not make much sense.

Comment: I tried the second link multipul times and every time after a restart the settings are lost.

Comment: Try to edit the settings while you are not connected to that Wifi. If that still not work then this is a bug of your device -> contact Samsung.

Comment: Thank you it works. It was because of a program we use. I deinstalled it and tried it again and it worked. I´m sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the network was added by a soti profile.

Comment: This Problem is solved with android enterprise of soti